# Update iPhone app before release

Tags: iphone, ios, appstore-approval

I have an iPhone app that's been approved but has a release date around 7 days from now. I want to add some very minor bug fixes so I'm going to submit a new binary.

If I submit the update, does that affect my ability to release the original version on its scheduled date, e.g. if the update was still in review at that stage?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your current version which has been approved will be released as scheduled regardless of if you submit an update for review. For your pending update, just add a new version with the version number bumped up and submit the binary as normal

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you need to change the binary, or in your case, reject the approved release, you will need to resubmit your binary and start the review process all over. You won't need to change any information with your meta information, but rejecting the binary effectively loses your place in line and you will have to start over. Your only option would be to wait until the app releases, then ship an update as soon as you are live.

Comment: Thanks, but I wouldn't reject the original as they are very minor changes. What I want to do is ensure that the original gets released, even if the update is still in review.

Comment: It shouldn't. As long as you don't reject the binary, it should release on schedule with no issues.